# Does Terraform locals visibility scope span children modules?

Tags: terraform

I've found that I can access a local coming from my root Terraform module in its children Terraform modules.
I thought that a local is scoped to the very module it's declared in.
See: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals#using-local-values

> A local value can only be accessed in expressions within the module where it was declared.

Seems like the documentation says locals shouldn't be visible outside their module. At my current level of Terraform knowledge I can't foresee what may be wrong with seeing locals of a root module in its children.

Does Terraform locals visibility scope span children (called) modules?
Why is that?
Is it intentional (by design) that a root local is visible in children modules?

**Details added later:**
Terraform version I use 1.1.5
My sample project:

```
.
├── childmodulecaller.tf
├── main.tf
└── child
    └── some.tf
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  a = 1
}
```

childmodulecaller.tf

```
locals {
  b = 2
}

module "child" {
  for_each = toset(try(local.a + local.b == 3, false) ? ["name"] : [])
  source = "./child"
}
```

some.tf

```
resource "local_file" "a_file" {
  filename = "${path.module}/file1"
  content = "foo!"
}
```

Now I see that my question was based on a wrongly interpreted observation.
Not sure if it is still of any value but leaving it explained.
Perhaps it can help someone else to understand the same and avoid the confusion I experienced and explained in my corrected answer.

Comment: What do you mean technically by "children modules"?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, by children I understand child modules as explained at https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module#calling-modules

Comment: The documentation says it does not do this, and in my experience it does not do this. Please show your code that is doing this.

Comment: Ok that documentation is inaccurate. We will assume you mean declared modules from the root module config directory and nested declared modules.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce this behavior, using Terraform 1.3.0. and I get the following: `Error: Reference to undeclared local value`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, could you point me to the correct documentation pages which use the terms you mention in you assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module has an entirely distinct namespace from others in the configuration.

The only way values can pass from one module to another is using input variables (from caller to callee) or output values (from callee to caller).

Local values from one module are never automatically visible in another module.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Corrected answer**

After reviewing my sample Terraform project code I see that my finding was wrong. The local a from main.tf I access in childmodulecaller.tf is actuallly accessed in a module block but still in the scope of my root module (I understand that is because childmodulecaller.tf is directly in the root module config dir). So I confused a module block in a calling parent with the child module called.

My experiments like changing child/some.tf the following way:

```
resource "local_file" "a_file" {
  filename = "${path.module}/file1"
  content = "foo!"
}

output "outa" {
  value = local.a
}

output "outb" {
  value = local.b
}
```

cause Error: Reference to undeclared local value
on `terraform validate` issued (similarly to what Mark B already mentioned in question comments for Terraform version 1.3.0)

So no, Terraform locals scope don't span children (called) modules.

**Initial wrong answer:**

I think I've understood why locals are visible in children modules.
It's because children (called) modules are included into the configuration of root (parent) module.

> To call a module means to include the contents of that module into the configuration with specific values for its input variables.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax#calling-a-child-module

So yes, it's by design and not a bug. Just it may be not clear from locals documentation. As root (parent) module's locals visible in children module parts of configuration which are essentially also parts of the root (parent) modules being included into the root (parent) module.

Comment: "with specific values for its input variables". Note the word **specific**. It's not referring to `locals` there at all. It is referring to the **specific** input variables that are declared in the `module`.